# Мультиклиентный чат на java, отвечающий только одному клиенту

Tags: java, java-ee, многопоточность

Разрабатываю сервер, который после приема сообщения обрабатывает это сообщение и отправляет ответ клиенту. За основу взял вот [этот образец](http://inetjava.sourceforge.net/lectures/part1_sockets/InetJava-1.9-Chat-Client-Server-Example.html). Проблема в том, что он отправляет ответ всем клиентам, а мне нужно чтобы только тому кто отправил запрос.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServerDispatcher extends Thread {
private List<String> mMessageQueue = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<ClientInfo> mClients =  new ArrayList<ClientInfo>();

/**
 * Adds given client to the server's client list.
 */
public synchronized void addClient(ClientInfo aClientInfo) {
    mClients.add(aClientInfo); 
}

/**
 * Deletes given client from the server's client list
 * if the client is in the list.
 */
public synchronized void deleteClient(ClientInfo aClientInfo) {
    int clientIndex = mClients.indexOf(aClientInfo);
    if (clientIndex != -1)
       mClients.remove(clientIndex);
}

/**
 * Adds given message to the dispatcher's message queue and notifies this
 * thread to wake up the message queue reader (getNextMessageFromQueue method).
 * dispatchMessage method is called by other threads (ClientListener) when
 * a message is arrived.
 */
 public synchronized void dispatchMessage(ClientInfo aClientInfo, String aMessage){
    Socket socket = aClientInfo.mSocket;
    String senderIP = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
    String senderPort = "" + socket.getPort();
    if aMessage.equals() {
        aMessage = .....
    } else {
        aMessage = .....
    }
    mMessageQueue.add(aMessage);
    notify();
}

/**
 * @return and deletes the next message from the message queue. If there is no
 * messages in the queue, falls in sleep until notified by dispatchMessage method.
 */
private synchronized String getNextMessageFromQueue()
throws InterruptedException {
    while (mMessageQueue.size()==0)
       wait();
    String message = (String) mMessageQueue.get(0);
    mMessageQueue.remove(0);
    return message;
}

/**
 * Sends given message to all clients in the client list. Actually the
 * message is added to the client sender thread's message queue and this
 * client sender thread is notified.
 */
private synchronized void sendMessageToAllClients(String aMessage) {
    for (int i=0; i < mClients.size(); i++) {
       ClientInfo clientInfo = (ClientInfo) mClients.get(i);
       clientInfo.mClientSender.sendMessage(aMessage);
    }
}

/**
 * Infinitely reads messages from the queue and dispatch them
 * to all clients connected to the server.
 */
public void run() {
    try {
       while (true) {
           String message = getNextMessageFromQueue();
           sendMessageToAllClients(message);
       }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
       // Thread interrupted. Stop its execution
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.е. фактически вы хотите сломать чат, и чтобы клиент видел только свои сообщения?
Если прям уж так сильно хотите это сделать, то в run() уберите вызов sendMessageToAllClients и замените на отправку сообщения тому кто его прислал.

Comment: только это будет уже не чат, а просто многопользовательский клиент-сервер